# Converting an unsigned int to an int pointer seg-fault

Tags: c, pointers, int, unsigned

I'm trying to convert an unsigned integer into to an integer pointer and I keep getting a segmentation fault, valgrind says invalid free(), delete, delete[], realloc(). I don't understand why I am getting this error because all the frees in the function are commented out and I protect against segfaults in the destroy function. Any ideas?

The test code:

```
void hugePrint(HugeInteger *p)
{
    int i;

    if (p == NULL || p->digits == NULL)
    {
        printf("(null pointer)\n");
        return;
    }

    for (i = p->length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    //printf(" i = %d  digit is: %d\n", i, p->digits[i]);
    printf("%d", p->digits[i]);
  printf("\n");
}

int main(void)
{
    HugeInteger *p;

    hugePrint(p = parseInt(246810));
    hugeDestroyer(p);

    return 0;
}
```

I use this struct:

```
    typedef struct HugeInteger
{
    // a dynamically allocated array to hold the digits of a huge integer
    int *digits;

    // the number of digits in the huge integer (approx. equal to array length)
    int length;
} HugeInteger;
```

My code:

```
#include "Fibonacci.h"
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include<stdio.h>
        HugeInteger *parseInt(unsigned int n)
        {
          HugeInteger *hugePtr = NULL;
          int parsedInt;
          //If any dynamic memory allocation functions fail within this function, return NULL, but be careful to avoid memory leaks when you do so.
          hugePtr = malloc(sizeof(HugeInteger));

          if(hugePtr == NULL)
          {
          //  free(hugePtr);
            return NULL;
          }

          // need to allocate for digits too, but how much memory for digits?
        //  hugePtr->digits = malloc(sizeof(int *));

        /*  if (hugePtr->digits == NULL)
          {
            return NULL;
          }
          */
          // Convert the unsigned integer n to HugeInteger format.
          //Need tp do boundary checks?
         // is this the right way to do it?
        //  parsedInt = (int)n;
          hugePtr->digits = (int *)n;
          hugePtr->length = 7;


          return hugePtr;
        }
        HugeInteger *hugeDestroyer(HugeInteger *p)
    {
    //  printf("in destroy\n");
      //If p is not already destroyed, destroy it
      if(p != NULL)
      {
        if(p->digits != NULL)
        {
          free(p->digits);
          free(p);
        }
        p = NULL;
      }
    //  printf("returning from destroy\n");
       return NULL;
    }
```

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) with definitions of structures used, inclusion of headers.

Comment: "is this the right way to do it?". No. `hugePtr->digits = &parsedInt` That makes a pointer to a *local* variable. The caller cannot use that pointer as the local variable goes out of scope when the function exits.

Comment: The title "Converting an unsigned int to an int pointer" looks confusing. I thought you are doing dangerous things such a `unsigned int a = 12345; int* p = (int*)a;` while actually you aren't. -- Oh... You *did* it in your edit... Too bad...

Comment: Would it still be dangerous with out-of-bounds checking added? I fixed the length (specific to this test case until I can write a function for length), however, I still get an error that says "invalid write of size four." I checked my malloc functions, however, as far as I can see I don't see an issue with them. I also don't see where I could possibly be going out of bounds. I'm fairly new to this, so I feel like it's something simple with the way i'm calling malloc. Do I need to call malloc for hugePtr->digits before I assign it a value too?

Answer (score 1):

*Undefined behavior* will be invoked because:

- A pointer converted from integer in implementation-defined way is assigned to `hugePtr->digits` and it may be dereferenced in `hugePrint`. The pointer has little chance to become a valid pointer.
- The value of `p->length`, which is allocated via `malloc()` and not initialized is used.

Avoid undefined behavior by:

- Allocate enough buffer via `malloc()` family and assign it to `hugePtr->digits`.
- Initialize `hugePtr->length`.